# Chromium move once Google Code becomes read-only

Tags: google-code

Chromium development is still very much active on [Google Code](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/list), which will turn read-only on August 25th 2015.

[image: Chromium on Google Code]

What are the plans to move Chromium development?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is asking particularly to the health and further actions of a particular project: Chromium. Questions that request for support of a particular open project should be asked with the project maintainers themselves, not Open Source SE.

Comment: -1 because there is an evident lack of research, see the answer below.

Comment: @MichaelSchumacher Evident lack of research? It looks like there has been research, and I'll tell you your reasoning for your downvote makes nearly no sense to me.

Comment: If there has been research, then why can there be an answer that is effectively "click on the link that is right there in your screenshot"? A well-researched question should acknowledge that.

Comment: @Zizouz212 lack of research is a very common and acceptable reason for downvoting.

Comment: @MichaelSchumacher Well, I disagree with your reasoning for the downvote, but whatever. You're entitled to your own opinion and actions :)

Comment: My apologies for the "lack of research". The "this post" link doesn't actually mention any specifics about what will happen to *Chromium* itself; it's a page about the fate of Google Code in general.

Comment: You did notice that Chromium is mentioned in the second paragraph on that page?

Answer (score 3):

If you click on the link "this post", you will see [this page](https://code.google.com/p/support/wiki/ReadOnlyTransition):

It contains more information about the process, including this  text:

> As [previously announced](http://google-opensource.blogspot.com/2015/03/farewell-to-google-code.html), **most of** Google Code will become read-only on August 25th, 2015.
>
> We are still working with Google-affiliated projects (e.g., [/p/chromium](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/) and [/p/android](https://code.google.com/p/android/)) to get them migrated to other tools and make their projects read-only by the end of the year. **These projects will remain read-write until we can transition all their data off of Google Code**. (my emphasis)

So it says that you will be able to work on *Chromium* (and *Android*) in read-write mode *until* Google decides where to migrate them to some other tool chosen by Google (e.g. GitHub).

*When* a decision to migrate is made, it will probably be announced on that same page.